# SQL windowing scope

Tags: sql, partitioning, windowing

I am learning how to use windowing functions and came across this SQL statement.

```
select
    ...
    sum(ss_ext_sales_price) * 100 / sum(sum(ss_ext_sales_price)) over (partition by i_class) as revenueratio

from
    ...
where
    ...
group by
    i_item_id,
    i_item_desc,
    i_category,
    i_class,
    i_current_price
```

My question is whether the `i_class` partition applies to all 3 of these `SUM` functions or whether some of them are calculated using the `group by` grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions and aggregation functions . . . they look very awkward when you first start using them together.  The partitioning clause has nothing to do with the first `sum()`, so let's just look at the denominator:

```
 sum( sum(ss_ext_sales_price) ) over (partition by i_class) as revenueratio
```

The `over` applies to the first `sum()`.  This is taking calculate the sum of the sum column . . . that is, the total amount.  I think it helped me to break this out:

```
 sum(ss_ext_sales_price)
 sum( sum(ss_ext_sales_price) ) over (partition by i_class) as revenueratio
```

In fact, you are not allowed to have a window function as an argument to an aggregation function:

```
 sum( sum(ss_ext_sales_price) over (partition by i_class) ) as revenueratio
```